# Windows 10 File History - how to check backup drive integrity?

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, file-history

Regarding Windows 10 File History backups on external drives.

Is there any way to check the integrity of the backup after it has been taken?

By integrity I mean I won't find I can't restore the files when I need to because the backup failed to complete correctly.

Comment: The integrity of the backup would be handled by the file system.  As pointed out by Christopher, File History isn't a backup, is a revision history of your file.  It can be used to recover a previous version of a document but it shouldn't be the your only backup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows 10 File History is not a great backup solution.  In fact, it's right there in the name - it's file history to see multiple revisions of a file, instead of a proper backup solution.  I suggest looking into backup products with automatic file verification and file checksums that you can verify independently.